# Can .aggregate() return me a events grouped by day of the month?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have an Event model in Mongoose as such:

```
let eventSchema = new Schema(
  {
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    start_time: { type: Date, required: true },
    end_time: { type: Date, required: true }
  }
);
```

I am trying to return them grouped by the day of the month so that I can parse them out onto a calendar. I thought using `.aggregate([])` and `$group` would do that for me. I am querying my Events collection like this:

```
exports.event_get = (req, res) => {
    let query = Event.aggregate([
        {$group: {
            _id: {
               date : { $dayOfMonth: '$start_time' }
        }}}
    ]).exec(function(err, e) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.send(e)
        }
    })
}
```

This is what I'm getting returned:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
       "date": 5
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
       "date": 1
    } 
  }
]
```

It is successfully grouping by date but I want to get the actual objects, not just this. Should I not be using `.aggregate()` for this? Is there another tool in Mongoose/MongoDB that will do that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add objects to your grouping results using `$push`. Each object is represented by [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) variable, so your aggregation could look like this:

```
exports.event_get = (req, res) => {
    let query = Event.aggregate([
        {$group: {
            _id: {
               date : { $dayOfMonth: '$start_time' }                   
            },
            {  objects: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
        }}
    ]).exec(function(err, e) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.send(e)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked with one slight modification. I had to add the `objects : { $push: "$$ROOT" }` outside of the `_id: {}`. Otherwise, I was getting an error saying `$push` wasn't a valid operator. Thank you!